# Can I get Windows Explorer to open to a location of my choosing?

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer

I'd like to have Windows Explorer open at my `C:\` drive when I press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, rather than at some to-me useless location; every single time I open Explorer (which I do a lot), I have to scroll down to C:\, etc. - a waste of time and an unwanted trip to Aggravation Station.

Comment: Putting files directly in C: is a very bad habit.

Comment: Why would you say that? I've always done that.

Comment: I used to do it to, back in the Windows 98 days, but now it's just wrong. For one, standard users only have read access at the root level by default, so it forces you to run as administrator. That by itself is reason enough.

Comment: Instead, you have a my documents folder, or a public users documents folder, or even the root of your profile folder, all of which are easy to access via the navigation pane in windows explorer.

Comment: I wasn't talking about putting files in C:\, but rather folders created in C:\ I hate the "My Documents" folder and all that crap.

Comment: Folders created in C:\ by default inherit permissions from C:\, and thus still are only read-only for standard accounts.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your explorer shortcut to: `%windir%\explorer.exe c:\`

Comment: As far as I know, the WinKey+E hotkey does not use a shortcut.

Comment: I thought it might be `C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools` but it isn't.... still trying to find where it is linked up at

Answer (score 2):

A normal Explorer shortcut can be modified as mentioned by Bryan (`explorer.exe <path>`).

To modify <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>'s default behaviour however, you'd need an [AutoHotKey script](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/customize-the-windows-e-key-shortcut-to-open-what-you-want/1188) like the following:

```
#e:: Run explorer.exe C:\
```

Comment: AutoHotKey is what I generally recommend for this as well.

Answer (score 2):

What I normally do is <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to bring up the run dialog. You can enter any path here and Explorer will open at that path. I prefer this over <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> because I have a number of network drives mapped that I will use as often as anything local.

Comment: That would be just as time-consuming and annoying.

Comment: The run dialog has autocomplete to make typing a path go very fast.

Comment: That only helps if you can recall the exact name of the path, which I usually can't; as Foghorn Leghorn said (I'm paraphrasing, perhaps), "I've got the memory of a sieve!"